# Seg Fault creating new QTcpSocket

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, qtcpsocket

I'm getting a segmentation fault when I try to create a new QTcpSocket:

```
QTcpSocket* socket = new QTcpSocket();
```

When I run I see the following:

```
$ ./hello 
Hello World
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm using Qt 5.11 on Unbuntu 17.04 and I'm not using qmake. I have created my own Makefile. I've checked and double checked the includes and libraries to for Qt 5.11 but not really sure if that is the issue because I can compile, link, and run just fine.

There seem to be 2 sets of areas where the Qt distribution resides which caused some confusion:

> ```
> $(HOME)Qt5.11.1/5.11.1/gcc_64 
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5
> ```

Here is my Makefile and code.

**hello.h**

```
#ifndef HELLO_H
#define HELLO_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpSocket>

class hello : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit hello(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:
    int test();

public slots:

private:

private slots:

};
#endif // HELLO_H
```

**hello.cpp**

```
#include "hello.h"

#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QDebug>

hello::hello(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    qDebug() << "Hello World\n";
    QTcpSocket* socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    emit test();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include "hello.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    hello h;

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Makefile**

```
####### Compiler, tools and options

CC      =       g++
DEFINES =       -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB
CFLAGS  =       -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC $(DEFINES)
INCPATH =       -I. \
                -I$(HOME)/Qt5.11.1/5.11.1/gcc_64/include \
                -I$(HOME)/Qt5.11.1/5.11.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore \
                -I$(HOME)/Qt5.11.1/5.11.1/gcc_64/include/QtNetwork \
                -I$(HOME)/Qt5.11.1/5.11.1/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++
LINK    =        g++
LFLAGS  =       -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,$(HOME)/Qt5.11.1/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib
LIBS    =       -L$(HOME)Qt5.11.1/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib \
                -L/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore \
                -L/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtNetwork \
                -lQt5Core -lQtNetwork
MOC     =       $(HOME)Qt5.11.1/5.11.1/gcc_64/bin/moc

####### Files

HEADERS =       hello.h
SOURCES =       hello.cpp \
                main.cpp
OBJECTS =       hello.o \
                main.o
SRCMOC  =       moc_hello.cpp
OBJMOC  =       moc_hello.o
TARGET  =       hello

####### Implicit rules

.SUFFIXES: .cpp

.cpp.o:
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o $@ $<

####### Build rules

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS) $(OBJMOC)
        $(LINK) $(LFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(OBJMOC) $(LIBS)

moc: $(SRCMOC)

clean:
        -rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(OBJMOC) $(SRCMOC) $(TARGET)
        -rm -f *~ core

####### Compile

hello.o: hello.cpp \
        hello.h \

main.o: main.cpp \
        hello.h \

moc_hello.o: moc_hello.cpp \
        hello.cpp \

moc_hello.cpp: hello.h
```

Here is the output of "ldd hello":

```
anshah@anshah-linux-laptop:~/test/hello$ ldd hello
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff2bff4000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /home/anshah/Qt5.11.1/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f5c4b903000)
libQtNetwork.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4 (0x00007f5c4b582000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f5c4b1fa000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f5c4afe3000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5c4ac1c000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5c4a9fc000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f5c4a7e0000)
libicui18n.so.56 => /home/anshah/Qt5.11.1/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib/libicui18n.so.56 (0x00007f5c4a347000)
libicuuc.so.56 => /home/anshah/Qt5.11.1/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so.56 (0x00007f5c49f8f000)
libicudata.so.56 => /home/anshah/Qt5.11.1/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib/libicudata.so.56 (0x00007f5c485ac000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5c483a8000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5c481a4000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5c47e90000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5c47b87000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000056357a3b1000)
libQtCore.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 (0x00007f5c47695000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f5c47422000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f5c47218000)
```

Comment: what is the output of: `ldd hello`

Comment: Output is too long I'll put it in "Answer Your Question" standby...

Comment: Much appreciated BTW

Comment: If it's too big then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53676231/edit) your question and add it there

Comment: Sorry about that...I added it to the original question and deleted it.

Comment: The problem is in your Makefile, I have compiled it with qmake and I link more libraries mainly related to OpenSSL than using Qt Network. What is the reason why create a Makefile manually? If you do not want to use qmake then use cmake or qbs.

Comment: In Qt Creator I had an issue with compiling non-C compatible code within an extern "C" { } block. The issues were mainly using bool/true/false, and function declarations with default parameters which are only compatible in C. I can't change it because it is checked in code. 
So I would get errors such as: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘=’ token ###
error: unknown type name ‘bool’ ###
error: ‘false’ [or true] undeclared (first use in this function) ###

Comment: Well, if I had your problem I would look for how to solve the boolean compatibility problem instead of creating my own Makefile since Qt is a gigantic project that links several backends, such as openssl, which are difficult to track. The problem you point out is one of them, prepare for those who come, good luck :-)

Comment: add `-DQT_NETWORK_LIB`

Comment: Nope still no luck.

Comment: I recommend you compile your test with qmake and see which flags you need to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There seem to be 2 sets of areas where the Qt distribution resides which caused some confusion:

That is very likely the root cause of your crash. If you compile against sources (header files) from one version of Qt, and then at run time use *different* version, a crash is very likely.

However, the root cause appears to be different: you are using *two* versions of `libQtCore`:

```
libQt5Core.so.5 => /home/anshah/Qt5.11.1/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5

libQtNetwork.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4
libQtCore.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
```

If these libraries define the same symbols (which seems very likely), then you are almost guaranteed to have a bad time due to symbol conflicts and/or wrong symbol being used.

The `libQtCore.so.4` is likely brought in as a dependency of `libQtNetwork.so.4`, and you probably shouldn't depend on `libQtNetwork.so.4` at all.

Your `Makefile` has:

```
-lQt5Core -lQtNetwork
```

The last entry should probably be `-lQt5Network` instead.

Comment: I think there was a remnant of Qt 4 which may be causing conflict. Do you suggest completely removing all Qt related modules and start fresh with latest 5.11?

Comment: What is the best way to cleanly remove all Qt remnants and start again fresh?